# Convert Token Numbers to Strings in ANTLR4

Tags: parsing, autocomplete, antlr, token, antlr4

I'm trying to use ANTLR4 to build a sort of autocomplete system using the `getExpectedTokens()` function that can be called when the parser experiences an error. `getExpectedTokens()` returns an IntervalSet, containing all the token numbers of the acceptable tokens at that point in the parse. Is there some mapping from the token numbers back to the actual Tokens themselves? (So, for example, if one of the expected tokens is a keyword that keyword can be displayed to the user in some way).

Answer (score 3):

These tokens names are accessible through the parser's vocabulary.

`parser.getVocabulary().getLiteralName(token_num)` will return the string of the literal tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Using `getSymbolicName()` worked for me.

So you could do `parser.getVocabulary().getSymbolicName(tokenType)` where `tokenType` is an int.